# Differentiate between authentication and return user on Facebook

Tags: facebook, authentication

How does one differentiate between authentication (first install) and return user ( user has already installed the app before and is returning on a day-to-day basis to use the app) in the new authentication model on Facebook?

[Facebook Authenication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) doesn't talk about this.

Previously in the old model there a couple of ways you could do that.

- Facebook had Post-Authorize callback URL
- Facebook used to send 'installed=1' variable as part of the query parameters.

Any help or pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After they authenticate with Facebook, log the unique user id that Facebook provides you and manually track this yourself in a database.  There is no other reliable method for this now because the callback url's are obsolete now.